# $P$ and $Q$ are independent, then we conclude that $\rho(P,Q)=0$

Tags: probability, statistics

HINT: 
Since we know that P and Q are independent, then the pair $(PQ^c)$, $(P^cQ)$, $(P^cQ^c)$ also independent.

Comment: This was discussed in-depth yesterday in [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) but the question seems to have been deleted there. The answer to the final question was no.

Comment: The vanish of correlation doesn't indicate that these two events are independent. Do you wanna ask about that?

Comment: The vanish of correlation indicates very much that these two events are independent.

Comment: (1.) Please stop the unorthodox notations. (2) Please read the answers and comments to your previous questions on MSE. (3) Please look for one or two definitions in Wikipedia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anybody reading the **definition** of [Pearson's correlation coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient#For_a_population) $\rho(X,Y)$ of two random variables $X$ and $Y$ defined on a common probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$  and applying it to the random variables $X=\mathbf 1_A$ and $Y=\mathbf 1_B$ for any $A$ and $B$ in $\mathcal F$ should see right away that
$$
\rho(\mathbf 1_A,\mathbf 1_B)=0\iff E[\mathbf 1_A\mathbf 1_B]-E[\mathbf 1_A]E[\mathbf 1_B]=0\iff P[A\cap B]-P[A]P[B]=0,
$$
that is,
$$
\rho(\mathbf 1_A,\mathbf 1_B)=0\iff (A,B)\ \text{independent}.
$$

Comment: thanks @did, any way in case if $A=B$ and $A=B^c$what will happen to the independence?

Comment: You should know that A and A=B are never independent except if P[A]=0 or P[A]=1. Likewise for A and A^c.